# Which regex is more efficient?

Tags: python, regex

```
s/(?P<head>\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc/\g<head>def
```

```
s/(?=\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc/def
```

Which is more efficient? Are there any other ways to make it more efficient? Please note that although I used Perl-style syntax for illustration purposes, I'm actually using Python's `re` library, which doesn't allow the `\K` (keep) keyword.

Comment: You may have to execute your regex in the order of 10-thousands or so and benchmark. It's hard to guess these things since each regex engine implementation has its own strength and weaknesses.

Comment: You can use timeit module (http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) to find out which is faster.

Comment: Efficient as far as time taken to do the query? It depends on what you are searching for, can you give an example?

Comment: FYI: Those regexs don't do the same thing *(In fact the second regex will never match anything.)* See: http://codepad.org/rW2bRKMH

Comment: @kudu Just a friendly reminder - If you feel one was helpful or answered the question, it is a good idea to accept an answer.  Doing so increases the likelyhood of others answering questions you may have in the future.

Comment: Sorry about that - I usually do it, but I haven't been on the site for a while. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(?P<head>\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc` in python using the `re` module is way faster:

```
import time
import re

rec1 = re.compile('(?P<head>\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc')
rec2 = re.compile('(?=\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc')

total1, total2 = 0.0, 0.0

def timeRE(ver):
    x = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_1234567890_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" * 100)
    t1 = time.time()
    if ver is 1:
        rec1.sub("def", x)
    else:
        rec2.sub("def", x)
    return (time.time() - t1)

for x in xrange(50000):
    total1 += timeRE(1)

for x in xrange(50000):
    total2 += timeRE(2)

print total1
print total2
```

Outputs:

```
4.27380466461
16.9591507912
```

---

### Edit (Run a few more times doing both calls in the same loop):

```
for x in xrange(50000):
    total1 += timeRE(1)
    total2 += timeRE(2)
```

Outputs:

```
4.26199269295
17.2384319305
```

---

### Edit (Fixing sub to match question):

```
import time
import re
rec1 = re.compile('(?P<head>\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc')
rec2 = re.compile('(?=\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc')
total1, total2 = 0.0, 0.0
def timeRE(ver):
    x = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_1234567890_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" * 100)
    t1 = time.time()
    if ver is 1:
        rec1.sub("\g<head>def", x)
    else:
        rec2.sub("def", x)
    return (time.time() - t1)

for x in xrange(50000):
    total1 += timeRE(1)
    total2 += timeRE(2)
print total1
print total2
```

Outputs:

```
Run 1:
4.62282061577
17.8212277889

Run 2:    
4.6660721302
17.1630160809

Run 3:
4.62124109268
17.21393013
```

---

### Edit (with a string that will match the REGEX):

```
import time
import re

rec1 = re.compile('(?P<head>\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc')
rec2 = re.compile('(?=\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc')
total1, total2 = 0.0, 0.0

def timeRE(ver):
    x = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_1234567890_<head>_<tail>_</head>_</tail>_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_<head>[[fooBAR_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abc]]]]defghiojklmnopqrstuvwyz" * 100)
    t1 = time.time()
    if ver is 1:
        rec1.sub("\g<head>def", x)
    else:
        rec2.sub("def", x)
    return (time.time() - t1)

for x in xrange(50000):
    total1 += timeRE(1)
    total2 += timeRE(2)

print total1
print total2
```

Output:

```
23.4271130562
29.6934807301
```

---

### And one final run:

```
import time
import re
rec1 = re.compile('(?P<head>\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc')
rec2 = re.compile('(?=\[\[foo[^\[]*)abc')
total1, total2 = 0.0, 0.0
def timeRE(ver):
    x = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_1234567890_<head>_<tail>_</head>_</tail>_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_<head>[[fooBAR_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abc]]]]defghiojklmnopqrstuvwyz" * 100)
    t1 = time.time()
    if ver is 1:
        rec1.sub("\g<head>def", x)
    else:
        rec2.sub("def", x)
    return (time.time() - t1)
for x in xrange(50000):
    total1 += timeRE(1)
    total2 += timeRE(2)
print "Method 1: Avg run took: %+0.7f - With a total of: %+0.7f" % ((total1 / 50000.0), total1)
print "Method 2: Avg run took: %+0.7f - With a total of: %+0.7f" % ((total2 / 50000.0), total2)
```

Output:

```
Method 1: Avg run took: +0.0004924 - With a total of: +24.6196477
Method 2: Avg run took: +0.0005921 - With a total of: +29.6053855
```

Comment: I would like to give you +1, but `rec1.sub("def", x)` should be `rec1.sub("\g<head>def", x)` based upon the OP. Could you run again with the correct replacement?

Comment: Still not right. Needs to be `\g<head>def` not `\g<head>`, though I'm guessing it won't affect the times since the regexs will never match and so will never make any replacements.

Comment: @jacob I just noticed that myself, fixing

Comment: Well, you already got my +1, but just fyi, the second regex (due to an error by the OP, not you) will never match anything and hence won't make any replacements. This is because it is doing a lookaround for `[[foo` and then trying to match `abc` over that. A lookbehind could fix it except that variable length lookbehinds aren't allowed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try it again with `(?<=\[\[foo)(?P<head>[^\[]*?)abc` as the second regex and `\g<head>def` as the replacement.

Comment: @alanmoore Method 1: Avg run took: +0.0020819 - With a total of: +104.0968215
Method 2: Avg run took: +0.0007138 - With a total of: +35.6894834